# Is anybody else getting errors when upgrading to com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0?

Tags: android, androidx

I was upgrading my material library in my Gradle file and suddenly I get this error.

```
\material-1.2.0-alpha04\res\values\values.xml:3360:5-3382:23: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/animationMode' with config ''.
```

I have already changed all libraries to androidX. Is there somebody who faces the same problem?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this ?

Comment: Im also getting the same error. For me, it happens for this library com.txusballesteros:FitChart:1.0 after I updated to androidx.

Comment: @Seyfullah have you got the solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on either all Android X, or all Support Library. If you're moving to Android X, make sure you have

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```

set to `true` in your gradle.properties file.

Comment: I have already done that, but still, it gives me the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<attr>`  of `animationMode` from `attrs.xml` then after rebuild project